# how to preprocess a local CSV file before upload

Tags: javascript, django, csv, web, file-upload

I'm working on a Django project where the user is able to upload a CSV file. 
What I want to do is that user can edit the local csv file , and apply the changes he wants to the csv values before upload.
I have tried the javascript FileReader API but it seams that it does not offer the editing possibility. 
Is there a way to do so ? Is there some tutorials that can help ? Thank you

Comment: You can't edit the file itself in a browser but can edit the data extracted from the file. Find an editable table script you like and use it's api to pass initial data to and after editing extract data from it to send to server

Comment: @charlietfl , thank you that was helpful :)